# What are the difference between Kerberos and UNIX security?

Tags: unix, hadoop, kerberos

I am learning Hadoop and trying to understand   the differences between Kerberos and UNIX security.

Comment: Great idea. Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: Kerberos deals with **authentication**, which is only a specific part of "security". And Unix systems can use Kerberos authentication, either directly (cf. `man sssd-krb5` / `man pam_krb5`) or thru the Microsoft Active Directory wrapper (cf. `man sssd-ad` and also `man pam_winbind` which are not related).